# Threading in GTK3 python

Tags: python, multithreading, gtk

I'm building a GTK GUI in Python and I need to get some data from the database which takes quite long, so the GUI freezes.

So I'm now using Threads to run the refreshing "in the background":

```
Thread(target=self.updateOrderList).start()
```

I have GUI class with alle relevant methods to manipulate the GUI. My solution work 80% of the time, but when it doesn't GTK crashed and it outputs this:

```
[xcb] Unknown request in queue while dequeuing
[xcb] Most likely this is a multi-threaded client and XInitThreads has not been called
[xcb] Aborting, sorry about that.
python3.6: ../../src/xcb_io.c:165: dequeue_pending_request:
```

The other times it works good, the data get loaded and its refreshing the gui.

edit: Sometimes I get this error:

```
Gdk-Message: 11:13:42.848: main.py: Fatal IO error 11 (Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar) on X server :0
```

Sometimes I click the refresh button several times and it works, but then it doesn't at some point.

My main.py looks like this:

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk, GObject

import gui

GObject.threads_init()

# start gui
gui.Gui()
Gtk.main()
```

Any ideas whats happening here?

Markus

Comment: could be related to order in which threads run; try to ensure the GUI is fully initialised before the background thread starts putting requests into the GUI (to experiment, introduce a sleep statement on commencing the background thread)

Comment: I tried but it gets triggered on a button, so waiting doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Relevant [handling-gtk-objects-on-threads-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33425202/handling-gtk-objects-on-threads-in-python)

Comment: @stovfl Thanks, might be a good solution. Do you know if it also possible to do this via signals/callbacks?

Comment: It's common sense to use `GLib.idle_add(self._callback)`, see [Possible solution for Threads](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55925063/7414759)

Answer (score 4):

Okay, GTK3 is not threadsafe. So I changed the program logic - doing requests in a new thread, and handling the GUI manipulation in the GUI thread **ONLY**. So that means I have to emit a "requests done" signal to the event loop:

Creating a new signal and registering it:

```
GObject.signal_new("my-custom-signal", self.window, GObject.SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT,
                       (GObject.TYPE_PYOBJECT,))
self.window.connect("my-custom-signal", self.updateOrderListCallback)
```

So when I click a button, start a thread:

```
Thread(target=self.updateOrderListThread).start()
```

In that thread, do the calculations, and then emit the signal:

```
self.window.emit("my-custom-signal", None)
```

so than the callback will be called after the calculations/requests/whatever are done and it works!